# Access a JS file from a different directory

Tags: javascript

I have a project with the following structure:

```
project | -

  public | -
    -index.html
  src | -
    -index.js
```

and the code to import the file is :

```
<script src="../src/index.js"></script>
```

and it doesn't work.
Any ideas why?

Comment: Not working, I'm accessing from a different folder to inside a different folder in the same parent folder

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that `public` is the only directory exposed with a URL (i.e. you access index.html with `http://example.com/index.html`): **you can't**.

The browser can only access the file by requesting its URL, and if you've not put it in `public` then it doesn't have a URL.

---

Either:

- Move the JS file
- Configure the server to give it a URL via some mechanism other than it being inside the document root.

Comment: I'm using express, any idea how I can send a whole folder?